# Load activity from save file

Tags: android, int, sharedpreferences

Straight to the point guys, I have made a game where once the user completes a level they are moved to next activity. So basically Activity1 complete then Activity 2 loads and so on.
I want to save the activity they get to then have a continue button on the main menu which will load it the next time they play. So far what i have done is save the progress to shared preferences using Int. But i cant work out how to call the values back so that the continue button knows which activity to load if that makes sence. Below is the code i am using to save the users progress, Im getting the feeling using Ints in this way may be the wrong way to do this so any advice would be great.  I am fairly new to android so nice clear answers would save me scratching my head haha :)

This is my success splash screen where i do the saving:

```
    public class success1 extends Activity {


    private boolean mIsBackButtonPressed;
    private static final int SPLASH_DURATION = 2000; // 2 seconds


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SharedPreferences sp =
                this.getSharedPreferences("GameProgress",0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = 
                sp.edit();
                editor.putInt("scene1",1);
                editor.commit();

        setContentView(R.layout.level_success);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);



        MediaPlayer player;
        AssetFileDescriptor afd;
        try {
        // Read the music file from the asset folder
        afd = getAssets().openFd("correct.mp3");
        // Creation of new media player;
        player = new MediaPlayer();
        // Set the player music source.
        player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
        // Set the looping and play the music.
        player.setLooping(false);
        player.prepare();
        player.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        finish();
        }

        Handler handler = new Handler();


        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {


                finish();

                if (!mIsBackButtonPressed) {
                    // start the home screen if the back button wasn't pressed already 
                    Intent intent = new Intent(success1.this, scene2.class);
                    success1.this.startActivity(intent);
                    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                    finish();
               }

            }

        }, SPLASH_DURATION); // time in milliseconds (1 second = 1000 milliseconds) until the run() method will be called

    }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {

        // set the flag to true so the next activity won't start up
        mIsBackButtonPressed = true;
        super.onBackPressed();

    }
}
```

This is just a debug main menu with a continue button:

```
public class DebugMain extends Activity {

    private Button button;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.debugmenu);

        addListenerOnButton();

    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        //Select a specific button to bundle it with the action you want
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


            }

        });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"*But i cant work out how to call the values back so that the continue button knows which activity to load if that makes sence.*"

On start when your Main Menu is loading, you should open your shared preferences file and read your int value. If you have for example 10 levels in your game, you can store one key/value pair. level: numOfLevel.

And when pressing continue button, you can write a switch(userLevel) { case 1: ... case 2:.... where each case would start a different activity based on the level you read when loading.

There really isnt much to it :) if it is a simple level structure like you said.